# how to see which port

Tags: networking, firefox

We know that when we connect to a http server then port 80 is used in server and a random port number in the client (web server).

I have three tabs opened in firefox. I have opened google, amazon, and gmail in each of those tabs respectively.

How can I see what port number is each of the http connection using. I am assuming those three tabs in firefox have three different http connection.

I am using firefox in ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

The command "netstat -tp" without quotes will give you all of your current connection status information such as local/foreign address and ports, protocol, etc.  If you expand your command terminal to the left/right to widen it out, the last column shows you the local program (and its PID) responsible for the connection.

[image: Screenshot of me running the command]

Answer (score 2):

The command `lsof -i :80` will show all active connections on port 80

[image]

it looks good when you use the `watch` command

```
watch -n 0 lsof -i :80
```

[image]